# How to check file permissions via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

To start out I am very new to this so please forgive me if this is extremely basic or I sound overly uninformed.

I would like to check all the files in a specific directory on my VPS to ensure that files are 644 and directories are 755. FTP is out of the question because there are far too many files/directories. SSH seems the most logical choice, but before i go chmod permissions I'd like to see what I'll be changing. Is there any way to find and display files/directories that do not meet this criteria?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a refinement to David Spillett's answer, how about using a single find command?  I think it's a bit cleaner than all the pipes, and calls to grep.  Furthemore, it cuts out a bit of the edge cases where this might blow up.

`find . -type f ! -perm 644` should find every file that doesn't have -rw-r--r-- permissions.  For directories, you can use `find . -type d ! -perm 755`.

Once you're happy with what you're seeing, you can even combine the chmod into the same command:

`find . -type f ! -perm 644 -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
`find . -type d ! -perm 755 -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful as well. Is the exclamation point the the part that reverses this? Could I do a find. f -perm 777 to find them as well?

Comment: Yeah, the `!` is basically `not`.  Using `find . -type f -perm 777` would only return those files that are 777, so if you're sure that's the only alternative, it would definitely work.

Comment: Its not the only alternative however I was using the "find all but" to narrow down the results so i could make the judgement call myself. I'm a little concerned that batch chmod is going to create some serious issues (i'm working on a live site). I generated a tarball with permissions included (or so I hope), but i'm still nervous.

Comment: Now just out of curiosity, could this be refined further to find the permissions of only public while group and owner remain irrelevant?

Comment: I understand the hesitation to using `find` with `-exec`.  It might help if you replace the `chmod` with `ls`.  That will just show you what it's going to do.  Or perhaps by preceding with `echo`, and writing the chmod commands to a file.  And the more you use it, the more comfortable it will be.  (Play around in test!)  As for your second comment, yes, you should be able to use `-perm -o=rwx` to match any rwx 'other' permissions.

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -l | grep -v rw-r--r--
```

"find all files in current directory, pass to "ls -l" to list their detail, and scan the output of `ls` for all the lines *not* (the -v option to grep negates the match) containing "rw-r--r--" and for directories:

```
find . -type d | xargs ls -l | grep -v drw-r--r--
```

If you want to scan another directory replace "." with it, such as:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f | xargs ls -l | grep -v rw-r--r--
```

and if some of the file/directory names might contain spaces use the "use 0-delimited strings" options in find and xargs like so to avoid errors:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | grep -v rw-r--r--
```

Also, you can remove the `-v` option from grep to find files/directories that *do* match, if you want to list these as a sanity check.

Using `find` will scan subdirectories too by default. To scan just one directory and not its children, you could just pipe the output of `ls -l` through `grep` instead of using `find` and `xargs`.

When you do run `chmod` remember that you can specify the `-v` option so it will list what it does and doesn't change as it performs the operation - this can be useful for reassuring yourself that you've given the right command.

Comment: Clever solution. I like it.

Comment: In crazy rare cases this may fail on files with names like rw-r-r--.jpg. "find . -type f | xargs ls -l | awk ' { if($1!="rw-r--r--") print $0} '" may work better. (i think!)

Comment: Or just use egrep and $rw-r--r-- Whatever works :p

Comment: Thank you very much, This is exactly what I needed and easy to understand!

Comment: find supports the -perm flag as well, find . -type f -perm 0644

Comment: @HampusLu: +1. I had a quick scan of the man page before answering as I though `find` might have such an option, but I didn't spot it.

Answer (score 0):

The following command should give you numerical permissions for all files in the specified directory

```
 stat -c "%a %n" /path/to/files/*
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response however the directory in question has many sub directories with more child directories and 10,000+ files. This is why I was hoping to just display files that weren't set to 644 and directories that aren't set to 755.

Comment: `find` and `grep` are your friends in that case, as you can see in the newer answer from David.

Answer (score -1):

See if the first answer to this works for you: [View permissions @stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338037/unix-how-to-check-permissions-of-a-specific-folder)